# Qt connect trying to use parent class

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

When I run my Qt program, I get this notice:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot SbSetting::checkbox_stateChanged(int)
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'cbEnableRetries')
```

The output is correct, there isn't any slot `SbSetting::checkbox_stateChanged(int)`. But that's not what I'm trying to connect to.

I have a class SbSetting. It isn't a top-level class, but I think the higher levels are inconsequential (it is a QObject.). Then I have the class IoRetrySetting, which inherits from SbSetting (`class IoRetrySetting : public SbSetting`). Here's what IoRetrySetting looks like.

```
IoRetrySetting::IoRetrySetting([...],
                               QCheckBox *cb,
                               [...])
    : checkbox(cb),
      SbSetting([...])
{
    if(!cb)
        new std::invalid_argument("cb cannot be null");

    connect(cb, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),
            this, SLOT(checkbox_stateChanged(int))); // <------  FAILS HERE
}

void IoRetrySetting::checkbox_stateChanged(int state)
{
    //...
}
```

Why is Qt looking in the parent class when I call connect? Why isn't it connecting to `IoRetrySetting::checkbox_stateChanged(int)`?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to `Q_OBJECT` to my class declaration. See also: https://forum.qt.io/topic/54289/qobject-connect-no-such-slot-qwidget-showtimee